# Conditional labeling and manual manipulation of labels in geom_text in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse, geom-text

Could anyone help me figure out how to:

1. Use `geom_text` to show labels only for those `down` and `up` categories (how to remove `stable` labels)
2. How to manually change negative labels to positive ones (erase minus sign from negative labels)
3. How efficiently use `hjust` to nudge positive labels to right and negative ones to left of the bars (I try something but wonder if there is better way than just doing it for all data one-by-one)

My desired output would be like this one below:
[image]

Code:

```
x <- LETTERS[1:11]
y <- c(9, 4, 6, 8, 5, 7, -9, -4, -6, -8, -5)
z <- seq(-1, 1, by = 0.2)

dat <- data.frame(x, y, z)

dat %>%
  filter(x != "B") %>%
  ggplot(aes(fct_reorder(x, y, .desc = T), y, 
             fill = ifelse(z > 0.7, "up", 
                           ifelse(z < -0.6, "down", "stable")))) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual("Color", 
                    values = c("up" = "#5b3b71", 
                               "down" = "#9a4054", 
                               "stable" = "#b7c1bd")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(y,"%")), 
            hjust = c(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_void()
```

Any help and advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Filter them out and preprocess all of your `dat` for this.
2. Use `abs()` in `geom_text()`
3. same as 1

try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
x <- LETTERS[1:11]
y <- c(9, 4, 6, 8, 5, 7, -9, -4, -6, -8, -5)
z <- seq(-1, 1, by = 0.2)

dat <- data.frame(x, y, z) |> 
  mutate(fill_col = ifelse(z > 0.7, "up", 
                           ifelse(z < -0.6, "down", "stable")),
         just_text = ifelse(z > 0, 1, 0)) |> 
  filter(x != "B")

dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(fct_reorder(x, y, .desc = T), y, 
             fill = fill_col)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual("Color", 
                    values = c("up" = "#5b3b71", 
                               "down" = "#9a4054", 
                               "stable" = "#b7c1bd")) +
  geom_text(
    data = dat |> filter(fill_col != "stable"),
    aes(label = paste0(abs(y),"%"), hjust = just_text)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_void()
```

outcome is:

[image]

Comment: This is great. Thanks, @Stephan. Just one quick question. I want to change the color of labels same as the color of bars. Would appreciate if you add this adjustment to your code.